# Mapserver 6.2 concatenate attributes in FILTER

Tags: mapserver, filter

Back in version 5.0 I had:

```
FILTER ("<tcode:expression/>" eq '[STATE][COUNTY]') 
final version = FILTER ("11000" eq '[STATE][COUNTY]')
```

so I would filter out the features with state = 11 and county = 000

Now, in 6.2, it does not work anymore. Does anyone know how to make it work with concatenated attributes?

I know that it would work like this:

```
FILTER ("11" eq '[STATE]' and "000" eq '[COUNTY]')
```

but it would really help me to find a way for the concatenation to work like:

```
FILTER ("11000" eq ('[STATE]'.'[COUNTY]')) -no error, but not display anything
```

Been browsing the documentation for a while but I just can't make this work.

Comment: Does it prompt any error if you do like this: FILTER ("11000" eq '[STATE][COUNTY]')?

Comment: Hello,

Yes, I get an error:
 Item &#39;STATE][COUNTY&#39; not found.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://mapserver.org/mapfile/expressions.html#string-operations-that-return-a-string, 
“String1” + “String2’
returns “String1String2”.

Comment: Great answer! This works
FILTER ("[ATTR_1]"+"[ATTR_2]"="Value1Value2")